# How to repeat a code when its statement is false [Python]

Tags: python

I really want to learn how do I repeat my code when its statement is false in Python. I just wanna know, how do I make Python ask for username and password again if its wrong? Here is my code:

```
print("Enter username")
username = input()
print("Enter password")
pword = input()
if username=="Shadow" and pword=="ItzShadow":
   print("Access granted to Shadow!")
else:
   print("Wrong username and / or password")
```

I meant, how can I make Python ask for Username and Password again if one of it is false?

Comment: Stay Cool Man ;-)

Comment: Place all your code in a `while True:` loop and after `print("Access granted to Shadow!")`, add a `break` statement.

Comment: If you enter "how do I repeat my code when its statement is false in Python" into the google search bar, you will find the answer quite quickly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 4):

You need to enclose your code in a loop. Something like this:

```
def get_user_pass():
   print("Enter username")
   username = input()
   print("Enter password")
   pword = input()
   return username, pword

username, pword = get_user_pass()
while not(username=="Shadow" and pword=="ItzShadow"):
   print("Wrong username and / or password")
   username, pword = get_user_pass()

print("Access granted to Shadow!")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a while loop:

```
while True:
    print("Enter username")
    username = input()
    print("Enter password")
    pword = input()
    if username=="Shadow" and pword=="ItzShadow":
        print("Access granted to Shadow!")
        break # Exit the loop
    else:
        print("Wrong username and / or password") # Will repeat

stuff() # Only executed when authenticated
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using the data entering function `get_input` in the loop each time the user and password aren't same.

```
def get_input():
# enter your declarations here
return [user_name,password]

user,pwd=get_input()
while (user!='your desired user' and pwd!='the password'):
    print('Not authorized')
    user,pwd=get_input()
print('Your success message')
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer?  You can use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for help.

Comment: @soundslikeodd We are using the data entring loop (get_input) each time the user and password aren't same

Comment: Please add this explanation to your answer.

Comment: @soundslikeodd Added